# PHP - displaying just PHP files from a directory and sub directories

Tags: php

This is my first project using PHP and I've been stuck on this for almost 2 days now!
I want to get all my PHP files from a directory and any sub directories and display them in iframes.
I've managed to get it to display all the files in the directory, but I only want the PHP files, please see below. Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

```
<?php
$path[] = 'work/*';

while(count($path) != 0)
{

$v = array_shift($path);
foreach(glob($v) as $item)
{
    if (is_dir($item))
        $path[] = $item . '/*';
    elseif (is_file($item))
    {
         printf(
  "<iframe width=420 height=150 frameborder=0 src='$item'></iframe>",
  ($file),$target);

    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
elseif (is_file($item))
```

To

```
elseif (is_file($item) && substr($item, -4) == '.php')
```

You can also use PHP's directory iterators, but the above is all you really need to do to get it working.

Eh, for fun, here's the iterator approach:

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('work');
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
$regex = new RegexIterator($iter, '/^.+\.php$/');

foreach($regex as $filename)
{
  // do something with $filename
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - Thanks so much for your help!! - I only wish I'd posted on here earlier!! Works a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

Change your glob pattern from `work/*` to `work/*.php`.

Comment: Then he'll lose his recursive directories.

Comment: @Matthew so run 2 glob, one with the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag and one with `*.php` inside each directory.

Answer (score 0):

Simple...replace `$path[] = 'work/*';` with `$path[] = 'work/*.php';`

You're already using `glob`, this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

You should have better code :)
I specially did not add iframe so you can edit it by yourself to get a bit more experience :)

```
<?php
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('work/');

$files_count = 0;

foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $filename => $cur) {
    $file_info = pathinfo($filename);

    if($file_info['extension'] === 'php') {
        $files_count++;
        echo $filename . "<br />";
    }
}

echo "Total: $files_count files<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you - I've got this to work as well - I appreciate you taking your time to post this. I just need to get the iframes to fill an area rather than in a long list. So where possible The iframes would populate width before height within a div (i.e. 2 columns).

Comment: it's html question :) you can change output and add html that you need there

Comment: Thought that was the case just wanted to make sure, just fiddling with it now, thanks again!

Comment: Ahhh, turns out is displaying my index.php files which are blank!! Just need to get it to ignore them, any ideas?